# CMake fails to detect Git version

Tags: git, cmake

When I run cmake (in order to [build TensorFlow on Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake)) I get the error message

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1811 (message):
  error: git version 1.6.5 or later required for 'git submodule update
  --recursive': GIT_VERSION_STRING=''
```

At lines 1810–1812 in `ExternalProject.cmake` I have these lines:

```
    if(GIT_VERSION_STRING VERSION_LESS 1.6.5)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "error: git version 1.6.5 or later required for 'git submodule update --recursive': GIT_VERSION_STRING='${GIT_VERSION_STRING}'")
    endif()
```

but I can't see where `GIT_VERSION_STRING` is assigned. Anyway it seems that `GIT_VERSION_STRING` is unassigned or assigned with an empty string or something something similar. This makes CMake fail to detect my Git version.

I have Git and `git --version` gives

```
git version 2.12.2.windows.2
```

Anyone knows what can be done about this error?

Comment: Can you show what's at `C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake:1811`, and possibly also your cmake code who trigger this call?

Comment: Make sure that a proper `git` has been found: check `GIT_EXECUTABLE` variable in CMake cache.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: What is the CMake cache and how do I check a variable there?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: There is a `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory, in which `GIT_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH` is set to a path that doesn't exist. Is there a way to reset this variable globally (or perhaps the entire cache)?

Comment: For reset this variable, remove record about it from the `CMakeCache.txt`. For reset whole cache delete whole file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I deleted `CMakeCache.txt` and now I don't get the same error, which is good. But the file didn't exist the first time I ran the command either, and then I did get the error. Why? And how can I make sure the error never occurs again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the file `CMakeCache.txt` in the folder from which I ran `cmake`, there was a variable called `GIT_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH` which for some reason pointed to the wrong path (I had Git installed but not in that folder). So I deleted `CMakeCache.txt` (according to  Tsyvarev's suggestion) and re-ran `cmake`, and I didn't have the same problem after than.

What I don't understand is why I `GIT_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH` was assigned an incorrect path the first time I ran `cmake` but not the second time. Where did that incorrect path come from? And why did I get the problem only once and not both times I ran `cmake`?

Answer (score 1):

Specify GIT_EXECUTABLE with path to your git.

It looks like cmake takes git from IDE by default. Visual Studio and Xcode provide git binaries too which is prefered by cmake and may be cause of the error about version mismatch.